# What object should implement NSCollectionViewDelegate?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-design-patterns

I have a subclassed `NSCollectionView` that is created in Interface Builder and is bound to an array.

I need to implement some of the delegate classes from `NSCollectionViewDelegate` but I'm kind of stumped as to what class to designate as the delegate.

Do I just create a random NSObject and designate it as the delegate? Do I create an NSViewController and designate *that* as the delegate—but if so, since the Collection View isn't being created programmatically, how do I tie the NSViewController to the Collection View?

*Any pointer to a good document that would explain stuff like this in Mac app architectural decisions would be a great bonus.*

Comment: It is common, but not mandatory, to make a view controller also be the delegate of the underlying view object. However, you can also make a new class as you suggest and use that. If that works for your overall architecture, do that. I am not making this an answer because I do not know of a good reference for you.

Comment: Thank you Michael. You did answer my question, so if you want to re-post this as an answer I will mark it as such. The reference would have been a bonus but is not essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common, but not mandatory, to make a view controller also be the delegate of the underlying view object. However, you can also make a new class as you suggest and use that. If that works for your overall architecture, do that.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of object is the File's Owner of the NIB? Most often, a NIB should be loaded and owned by either an `NSWindowController` or `NSViewController` (or subclass of one of those). That controller would typically be responsible for everything in the NIB, so it would be the delegate.

If it makes sense, you might put the collection view into a NIB all its own. You'd create a subclass of `NSViewController` to load and own the NIB and set the class of the File's Owner placeholder in the NIB to that class. You'd connect the `view` outlet of File's Owner to the collection view and the `delegate` outlet of the collection view to File's Owner.

Comment: Thanks, Ken. Since I'm not creating the Collection View programmatically but through Interface Builder, in the default xib, it doesn't have its own xib. I dragged a View Controller object into IB and created a custom class, then hooked up its view outlet to the Collection View, which made the controller own it.